# In React Native, is it possible to detect a swipe vs a tap in Pan Responder's onStartShouldSetPanResponder?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Right now, I return a `true` in my `onStartShouldSetPanResponder`, and as a result the PanResponder wants to handle taps AND pans. Is there any way to restrict it to just pans, as I want a `TouchableHighlight` to handle that? (I get that the Gesture Responder should handle both, but it seems weird that the "Pan" Responder handles taps)

Since the gesture is just starting, the `dx`/`dy` are 0 in `onStartShouldSetPanResponder`. Is there any way to detect if it's the start of a tap and return false, if so?

Or should I just detect whether it was a tap or pan in the `OnPanResponderRelease`?

Answer (score 4):

I was able to accomplish this through the onMoveShouldSetPanResponder method as follows:

```
onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
    return Math.abs(gestureState.dx) >= 1 || Math.abs(gestureState.dy) >= 1
}
```

If the x or y movement is greater than 1, return true. In order to then detect a tap, I had to wrap everything within my view containing the panHandlers with a touchable element. Here is a full working example:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Animated, PanResponder, Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View>
      <CircleTapExample/>
    </View>
  );
}

class CircleTapExample extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.position = new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 0, y: 0 });
        this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponder: (evt, gestureState) => {
              return Math.abs(gestureState.dx) >= 1 || Math.abs(gestureState.dy) >= 1
            },
            onPanResponderMove: (evt, gestureState) => {
                console.log("I was moved")
                this.position.setValue({ x: gestureState.moveX, y: gestureState.moveY })
            },
        });
    }
    
    circleTapped() {
        // Do something here when tapped
        console.log("I was tapped")
    }
    
    render() {
        return (
            <Animated.View style={[styles.container, { ...this.position.getLayout() }]} {...this.panResponder.panHandlers}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.circleTapped()} style={{ flex: 1 }}>
                    <View style={styles.circle} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </Animated.View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
      width: 75,
      height: 75,
      bottom: 5,
      left: 5,
      position: 'absolute'
  },
  circle: {
      width: 75,
      height: 75,
      borderRadius: 40,
      backgroundColor: 'red'
  }
});
```

```html
<div data-snack-id="YskU-lxRe" data-snack-platform="web" data-snack-preview="true" data-snack-theme="light" style="overflow:hidden;background:#F9F9F9;border:1px solid var(--color-border);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"></div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.dev/embed.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The panResponder has two events :

- onStartShouldSetPanResponder(Capture)
- onMoveShouldSetPanResponder(Capture)

I've been able to solve this problem only by **removing onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture**.